# Placing a kth adjacent term in a row of k-1 non-adjacent terms

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions

The question is:

If I have a binary string (leading digits can be $0$) of length $a$ with $b-1$ nonadjacent $1$s, what is the sum of the number of ways to place the $b$th $1$ such that it is adjacent to at least $1$ other $1$?

For example if $a=4$ and $b=3$,

$1010$ -> $2$ ways

$1001$ -> $2$ ways

$0101$ -> $2$ ways

So the total sum of the ways is $6$.

I have computed for small cases:

$(a, b)$ -> sum of ways

$(3, 2)$ -> $4$

$(3, 3)$ -> $1$

$(4, 2)$ -> $6$

$(4, 3)$ -> $6$

But I am unsure how to progress, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N(a,b)$ denote the wanted number of words obtained by counting all binary words of length $a\geq 2$ containing $b$ $1$s with

- either $b-2$ non-consecutive $1$s and one run of $1$s with length $2$ (counted twice),
- or $b-3$ non-consecutive $1$s and one run of $1$s with length $3$ (counted once).

The first case corresponds to the substitution of $0$s if we have a pattern of the form
\begin{align*}
xxx0010xxx\to xxx0110xxx\\
xxx0100xxx\to xxx0110xxx\\
\end{align*}
Since there are two different patterns which both give the same result, we have to count it twice. The second case corresponds to the substitution of $0$ if we have a pattern of the form
\begin{align*}
xxx01010xxx\to xxx01110xxx\\
\end{align*}

A table with non-zero values $N(a,b)$, $2\leq b\leq a\leq 10$ with values calculated by OP marked in blue is given below.
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{r|rrrrr}
a\backslash b&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
2&2\\
3&\color{blue}{4}&\color{blue}{1}\\
4&\color{blue}{6}&\color{blue}{6}\\
5&8&15&2\\
6&10&28&12\\
7&12&45&36&3\\
8&14&66&80&20\\
9&16&91&150&70&4\\
10&18&120&252&180&30
\end{array}
\end{align*}

> We show the following is valid for $a\geq 2$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N(a,b)=\begin{cases}(a-b+1)\left(2\binom{a-b}{b-2}+\binom{a-b}{b-3}\right)&\quad 2\leq b \leq \left\lfloor\frac{a+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\quad\tag{1}\\
> 0&\quad \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}}
> \end{align*}

We use generating functions in order to derive $N(a,b)$ and start with generating functions of binary **Smirnov words**. These are words with no equal consecutive characters. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.) Encoding $0$s with $x$ and $1$s with $y$ the generating function of Smirnov words is
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{y}{1+y}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The coefficient of $x^py^q$ in the generating function above gives all words of length $p+q$ with no runs of $0$s or $1$ with length $>1$. This is a convenient first step but we need some adaptations. At first we note that the runs of $0$s are not restricted. We therefore substitute occurrences of $0$s with one or more $0$s.
\begin{align*}
x\quad\to\quad x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=\frac{x}{1-x}
\end{align*}
Each of the wanted words has either one run of two $1$s or one run of three $1$s. We respect this by substituting
\begin{align*}
y\quad\to\quad y+sy^2+ty^3
\end{align*}
We additionally mark $y^2$ with $s$ and $y^3$ with $t$ to be able to extract zero or one terms of them.

> We obtain using the generating function (2) and the substitutions above the wanted generating function
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(x,y;s,t)}&=\left(1-\frac{\frac{x}{1-x}}{1+\frac{x}{1-x}}-\frac{y+sy^2+ty^3}{1+y+sy^2+ty^3}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1+y+sy^2+ty^3}{1-x-xy-xsy^2-txy^3}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Since we are looking for words of length $a$ with $b$ $1$s, the number of $0$s is $b-a$ and we are looking for coefficients $[x^{a-b}y^b]$ in $A(x,y;s,t)$. We have either a $2$-run of $1$ weighted by $2$ since $11$ comes from $01$ or $10$ and a $3$-run of $1$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N(a,b)=\left(2[x^{a-b}y^bs^1t^0]+[x^{a-b}y^bs^0t^1]\right)A(x,y;s,t)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

**Step 1: Expansion in powers of $t$**

We start calculating (4) by expanding (3) in powers of $t$.

\begin{align*}
&A(x,y;s,t)=\frac{1+y+sy^2+ty^3}{1-x-xy-xsy^2-txy^3}\\
&\qquad=\frac{1+y+sy^2+ty^3}{\left(1-x-xy-sxy^2\right)\left(1-\frac{xy^3}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}t\right)}\\
&\qquad=\frac{1+y+sy^2+ty^3}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{xy^3}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}\right)^nt^n\\
&\qquad=\frac{1+y+sy^2+ty^3}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}\left(1+\frac{xy^3}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}t+O\left(t^2\right)\right)\tag{5.1}
\end{align*}

We extract coefficients of $t^0$ and $t^1$:
\begin{align*}
[t^0](A(x.y;s,t)&=\frac{1+y+sy^2}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}\tag{5.2}\\
[t^1]A(x,y;s,t)&=\frac{\left(1+y+sy^2\right)xy^3}{\left(1-x-xy-sxy^2\right)^2}+\frac{y^3}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}\\
&=\frac{y^3}{\left(1-x-xy-sxy^2\right)^2}\tag{5.3}\\
\end{align*}

> and obtain from (5.1) to (5.3)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N(a,b)}&\color{blue}{=2[x^{a-b}y^bs^1]\frac{1+y+sy^2}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+[x^{a-b}y^bs^0]\frac{y^3}{\left(1-x-xy-sxy^2\right)^2}}\tag{5.4}
> \end{align*}

**Step 2: Expansion in powers of $s$**

We extract from (5.4) coefficients of $s^0$ and $s^1$:
\begin{align*}
[s^0]&\frac{y^3}{(1-x-xy-sxy)^2}=\frac{y^3}{(1-x-xy)^2}\tag{6.1}\\
[s^1]&\frac{1+y+sy^2}{1-x-xy-sxy^2}\\
&=[s^1]\frac{1+y+sy^2}{(1-x-xy)\left(1-\frac{xy^2}{1-x-xy}s\right)}\\
&=[s^1]\frac{1+y+sy^2}{(1-x-xy)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{xy^2}{1-x-xy}\right)^ns^n\\
&=\frac{(1+y)xy^2}{(1-x-xy)^2}+\frac{y^2}{1-x-xy}\\
&=\frac{y^2}{(1-x-xy)^2}\tag{6.2}
\end{align*}

**Step 3: Expansion in powers of $x$ and $y$**

> We finally obtain $N(a,b)$ from (5.4), (6.1) and (6.2) by extracting coefficients of $x^{a-b}$ and $y^b$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N(a,b)}&=2[x^{a-b}y^b]\frac{y^2}{\left(1-x(1+y)\right)^2}+[x^{a-b}y^b]\frac{y^3}{\left(1-x(1+y)^2\right)}\\
> &=2[x^{a-b}y^{b-2}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n(1+y)^n\\
> &\qquad+[x^{a-b}y^{b-3}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n(1+y)^n\\
> &=2(a-b+1)\binom{a-b}{b-2}+(a-b+1)\binom{a-b}{b-3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(a-b+1)\left(2\binom{a-b}{b-2}+\binom{a-b}{b-3}\right)}\tag{6.3}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.